# Constructing a subsequence that converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Construct a sequence $z_k\in \Bbb R^2$ with the property that for any $z=(x,y)$ such that $x^2+y^2=1$, there exists a subsequence $z_{k_{n}}$ such that $z_{k_{n}}\to z$.

Can someone please help me with this question?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Think about a sequence given by $e^{in \pi r}$ such that $r$ is irrational. Can you prove that this sequence has the property you want?

Comment: Not sure we need to get that fancy for this one.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $q_1,q_2,\dots $ be the rationals in $[0,2\pi).$ Consider $z_k = e^{iq_k}, k = 1,2,\dots $